# How do I enable an init.d script offline?

Tags: scripting, filesystems

My problem is quite simple but I can't find any solution online:
I have a file system containing an init.d script. I want this script to be run at first boot of the system. How do I do this? I'd like to avoid creating init.d symlinks manually if possible.

Edit: I'm using Debian 4.19. The file system containing the init.d script is the rootfs of the final system. By first boot I mean I want the script to be run the first time I boot a machine using the file system where it's located (the kernel I'm using will also be booting for the first time but I don't think it matters). I'd like to maintain this init.d script and not move to any other service management if possible. Basically the problem is simple: I have access to the linux file system I want to boot and I want to enable an init.d script without booting the whole system.

Comment: What exactly is this *system* you want your script to be run in? Which OS version? Which distribution if it is Linux? Does it even use SysVinit, or does it use `systemd`, or something else like `launchd` on macOS or SMF on Solaris? Is the *file system* you mentioned one that the OS will mount as standard, or do you need some customization to get it mounted first? With *first boot* do you mean a freshly installed OS that has never booted on its own before? Please *edit your question to add more information*.

Comment: I added some info regarding the os/distribution version I'm using. I'm not sure about sysvinit and systemd. As far as I know the official service manager on debian is systemd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, "Debian 4.19" does not exist: you are probably looking at a Debian system with a *Linux kernel version 4.19* which would mean it's a **Debian 10** ("buster", the release that became "oldstable" as Debian 11 was released just about two weeks ago).

Debian has been using `systemd` since Debian 8, but they still maintain some SysVinit compatibility and an option to replace `systemd` with other init systems... although I don't know how practical it would actually be to use SysVinit in Debian 10, as quite a lot of system integration now benefits from or relies on `systemd`. But `systemd` on Debian 10 (and also 11) still has the complete compatibility mechanism for init.d scripts, so this answer should be applicable no matter which init system is used.

So, you have a disk that contains a Debian 10 installation root partition as e.g. `/dev/sdXN` and you want to modify it to add and init.d script, before that system is actually booted up.

You could mount the disk in another system:

```
mount /dev/sdXN /mnt
```

Then copy your script into the new installation's `/etc/init.d/` directory:

```
cp /some/where/myscript /mnt/etc/init.d/
chmod a+rx /mnt/etc/init.d/myscript
```

Note: for `systemd` compatibility, your script needs to include the LSB-style comment block in the beginning, to document its dependencies and prevent `systemd` from running it too early in the start-up process. [See this Debian Wiki article](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) or [`insserv(8)` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/insserv/insserv.8.en.html) for more details.

Basically, your script must have a comment block like this in the beginning of the script *before any other non-comment lines*:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myscript
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start myscript at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by myscript.
### END INIT INFO
```

You should adjust the `Required-Start` and `Required-Stop` lines according to your script's requirements.

Once your script is in place, you can `chroot` into the new installation in order to run the [`update-rc.d`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/init-system-helpers/update-rc.d.8.en.html) tool to create the init.d symlinks for you. But before the actual chroot command, you should mount the `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev` filesystems or else you won't be able to do much:

```
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/sys
mount -o rbind /dev /mnt/dev
chroot /mnt /bin/bash  # From this point on, /mnt will be this session's root directory
```

Now your session will be running "within" the new installation's environment, and you can use most tools of that installation just as if the system was already running the new installation. So, you can use the `update-rc.d` command:

```
/usr/sbin/update-rc.d myscript defaults
```

After this, you can undo the chroot and unmount the new installation's root filesystem to cleanly end the procedure:

```
exit  # back to having the real root directory
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt
```

(The procedure of mounting the root filesystem of an inactive installation is applicable for many maintenance and troubleshooting situations, like fixing a damaged bootloader or changing a lost root password. In this specific case, it might not be necessary to mount `/proc` and `/sys` within the inactive installation... but I chose to show the chroot procedure in an "universal" form, so it will be more easily applicable to other situations too.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I'm already aware of the requirements regarding the header of the script. Unfortunately, the system I'm using to copy the script into the new fs does not have root permissions and I'm already using a trick to go around mount commands. Based on other research I think I'm probably going to move to systemd.